# Docker on windows server 2019 error 4294967295

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

I am trying to run a linux centos image wiht python3.6

When i run it we get the error :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Cannot open: https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
The command '/bin/sh -c yum update -y     && yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm     && yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip     && yum install -y which gcc     && yum install -y openldap-devel' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295
```

What is this error code 4294967295 ?